# Using Airflow's HttpSensor with a unique X-Request-ID header on each request

Tags: airflow, uuid, http-get, airflow-2.x

I want to monitor an endpoint via a HTTP GET Request until I see a "SUCCESS".

The endpoint requires a unique X-Request-ID header on each request. If I do not include this field, or if I send the same UUID twice, I get a 400 Bad Request back. I tried:

```
monitor_job = HttpSensor(
    task_id = 'monitor_job',
    http_conn_id='',
    endpoint='http://some_endpoint',
    request_params={},
    response_check=lambda response: 'SUCCESS' in response.text,
    poke_interval=5,
    dag=dag,
    headers={
        'X-Request-ID': str(uuid.uuid4()) #returns a random uuid
    }
)
```

I am seeing that the first GET request works fine, it waits 5 seconds, but the next GET request fails, as it tries to send a request with the same GUID. I'd need it to send a new value in the X-Request-ID header on each request.

Is this possible with HttpSensor or otherwise?

---

The best alternative approach I can think of would be to move the GET request into a loop in python code (probably using the requests library), and use a PythonSensor. This is more code to write and it feels like a workaround.

I am not currently using http_conn_id just to match style with related code in the codebase. I can use it if it would help.

I'm running on Airflow v2.2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run the sensor in mode `poke`, the task will be created once, and put to sleep between pokes. In this case, `uuid.uuid4()` will be called once and you will have the same uuid for all the queries:

- you can change the mode to `reschedule`:

```py
monitor_job = HttpSensor(
    task_id = 'monitor_job',
    http_conn_id='',
    endpoint='http://some_endpoint',
    request_params={},
    response_check=lambda response: 'SUCCESS' in response.text,
    poke_interval=5,
    dag=dag,
    headers={
        'X-Request-ID': str(uuid.uuid4()) #returns a random uuid
    },
   mode="reschedule",
)
```

- you can override the the sensor code to change the headers value:

```py
class MyHttpSensor(HttpSensor):
    def poke(self, context: Context) -> bool:
        self.headers = {
            'X-Request-ID': str(uuid.uuid4())
        }
        return super().poke(context)
monitor_job = MyHttpSensor(
    task_id = 'monitor_job',
    http_conn_id='',
    endpoint='http://some_endpoint',
    request_params={},
    response_check=lambda response: 'SUCCESS' in response.text,
    poke_interval=5,
    dag=dag,
)
```

- you can also override the sensor and call the method `render_template_fields` on each poke, then provide the `X-Request-ID` as a jinja template:

```py
class MyHttpSensor(HttpSensor):
    def poke(self, context: Context) -> bool:
        self.render_template_fields(context)
        return super().poke(context)
monitor_job = MyHttpSensor(
    task_id = 'monitor_job',
    http_conn_id='',
    endpoint='http://some_endpoint',
    request_params={},
    response_check=lambda response: 'SUCCESS' in response.text,
    poke_interval=5,
    dag=dag,
    headers={
        'X-Request-ID': "{{ uuid.uuid4() }}"
    },
)
```

I recommend the second option, but if your API takes much time to be "SUCCESS", then the first one is the best with `poke_interval` >= 60, in order to release the worker slot and let the worker runs other tasks.

Comment: You can use `Dict` but officially it's [Context](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/sensors/base.py#L162). And context is [MutableMapping\[str, Any\]](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/utils/context.py#L158), it can help the developer to detect the bugs in compilation time and it autocomplete the code.